# How to enable validation for datetime_select field in a Rails form?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a rails form:

```
<%= form_for(@product) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name, :id => "txt1" %>
    <%= f.label :release_date %><br>
    <%= f.datetime_select :release_date, :start_year => Time.now.year %>
    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

I need to validate the release_date. The validation is like, user should not be able select a date and time that is less than the current date and time.

Is it possible to validate it in rails way, like what I have done with `start_year` or should I use client side validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this, I have not tested this but you can try

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    validate :released_valid_datetime

    def released_valid_datetime
        errors.add(:release_date, 'date should be lesser') if (release_date < Time.zone.now)
    end
end
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I needed. The user should not be able to select a wrong release_date without a model validation also.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) gem:

and this many options in your forms:

```
<%= f.input :date_of_birth, as: :date, start_year: Date.today.year - 90,
                          end_year: Date.today.year - 12, discard_day: true,
                          order: [:month, :year] %>
```

and

```
<%= f.input :age, collection: 18..60, prompt: "Select your age"%>
```